# retrieve an entity with a key from datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to retrieve an entity from my database using its id.
I've tried using all kind of commands but the result stays the same , I always get an empty entity. I know the id is correct because I run a query on my database and receive this id.
this is how i receive the id from my database

```
Object course = courseList.get(0).getKey().getId();
```

I tried creating a key from that id and use

```
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("courses", course);
db.get(key);
```

even tried run a query on database with that key.I can see the the query is correct but I still receive an empty entity:

```
Query query = new Query("Courses").setFilter(Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL.of(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY, key));
```

and also like that

```
Query query = new Query("Courses").setFilter(Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL.of("__Key__", key));
```

I'm out of ideas ... what am I doing wrong? I know for sure this key exist.In debug mode I can see this key.I see it also in my database.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I never played with Java too much but from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata#Getting_an_Object_By_Key) something like this should work:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
Courses c = pm.getObjectById(Cources.class, course);
```